# Getting "Expected a type" error in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm getting this error:

/Class/GData/OAuth/GDataOAuthViewControllerTouch.m:116:22: Expected a type

That line is:

```
 authentication:(GDataOAuthAuthentication *)auth
```

Inside of this block of code:

```
- (id)initWithScope:(NSString *)scope
           language:(NSString *)language
    requestTokenURL:(NSURL *)requestURL
  authorizeTokenURL:(NSURL *)authorizeURL
     accessTokenURL:(NSURL *)accessURL
     authentication:(GDataOAuthAuthentication *)auth
     appServiceName:(NSString *)keychainAppServiceName
           delegate:(id)delegate
   finishedSelector:(SEL)finishedSelector {

  NSString *nibName = [[self class] authNibName];
```

I'm a newb XCode developer. So far I've created and compiled a calculator app based from an online class but that's it.

Is this a library that is not being included?

Background: The previous developer abandoned the project and the owner sent the project code to me. I'm trying to replace the existing graphics with new graphics and recompile it with support for iOS 6, which I thought I should be able to do without any coding, but have run into this error and many others when I opened the project. I have the latest XCode.

Comment: Please provide the surrounding code - it's difficult to identify the exact problem without seeing the context.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to look for:

Did you #import the file where the **GDataOAuthAuthentication** type is defined? (e.g. #import "GDataOAuthAuthentication.h")

Is there a variable named GDataOAuthAuthentication which is causing the compiler to think **GDataOAuthAuthentication** is a variable not a type?

Comment: The file has the import statement just as you wrote it at the top but I don't see the file "GDataOAuthAuthentication.h" in the project files. There are 12 files that start with GDataOAuth in the project but GDataOAuthAuthentication is not one of them.

Comment: I'm guessing this is the source of the project files: [rpetrich/gdata-objectivec-client](https://github.com/rpetrich/gdata-objectivec-client)  You may need to readd those files to your project.

Answer (score 0):

The `:22` (and the position of the caret within the editor) tell you exactly where on the line the error is. In this case it's telling you that where it sees `GDataOAuthAuthentication` it was expecting a type. So, implicitly, it doesn't recognise that `GDataOAuthAuthentication` is a type.

Objective-C still sits upon compilation units ala C — each .m file is compiled in isolation then the lot are linked together. You use `#import` (or `#include` if you want; `#import` just guarantees the same file won't be included twice) to give each individual file visible sight of any external definitions it needs.

So, that's a long-winded way of reaching the same conclusion as Rick did five minutes ago: you've probably omitted a necessary `#import`.